# change facebook tabs visualization

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-page

I want to change the standard tab visualization of applications on my fan page in the new profile way visualization (tab in a box on the right), like in Manchester United Fan Page

http://www.facebook.com/manchesterunited

Is it possible now?

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://www.facebook.com/pages/manage/
Then click on button "Upgrade my pages" and select witch pages do you wan to switch to new layout by clicking the button "Upgrade" next to them ;)